# How to create a collection automatically in mongoDB if it's not already there?

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose, schema

I am creating passport authentication for node using mongoose. I don't have any collection called "users" in my database. But while creating new user using the schema like below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{
id: String,
username: String,
password: String,
email: String,
firstName: String,
lastName: String
});
```

It will automatically creates new "users" collection.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 18):

Here mongoose will check if there is a collection called **"Users"** exists in MongoDB if it does not exist then it creates it. The reason being, mongoose appends **'s'** to the model name specified. In this case **'User'** and ends up creating a new collection called **'Users'**. If you had specified the model name as **'Person'**, then it will end up creating a collection called **'Persons'** if a collection with the same name does not exist.

Comment: but how can we restrict this automatic creation of collection. As don't want it.

Comment: That is how mongoose works, you cannot restrict it. Refer this link : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Use Spring Data instead. Because :extensive documentation and large developer community.

Comment: From the 'guide' link that @vmr posted above:  "option: collection -- Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. Set this option if you need a different name for your collection."

Answer (score 5):

Mongoose pluralizes the model name and uses that as the collection name by defualt. If you don't want the default behavior, you can supply your own name:

```
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ ... }, { collection: 'User' }));
```

Ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection